# Serve Angular14 without minification/uglification

Tags: angular, optimization

Is there a way to disable all sorts of minification/uglification in the SERVE process, so it doesn't rename class names that are part of the error message?

It's the last Angular14 version.

**Error message I'm receiving:**

> 

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(i)[e -> InjectionToken Application Initializer -> [object Object] -> j -> b -> Tt -> J -> Tt -> Tt -> Tt]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Tt!

> 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serve process should NOT minify and uglify your code.

If it does, check your `angular.json` file and in the serve part, set this

```
"buildOptimizer": false,
"optimization": false,
"vendorChunk": true,
"extractLicenses": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"namedChunks": true
```

Comment: These options seem to be fit for the **build** section, but VSC tells me that they are invalid for the **serve** section. In what exact part of the **serve** configuration should they be used?

Comment: Thanks, helped me to solve the issue. Actually, the point is that angular.json was obviously quite changed since the last version I used (11), so now I fixed it according to a clean generated templated, which seems to do the job right.

Comment: Glad you could resolve it ! Although for the record, it's probably not the file that changed, but someone that changed the file (it has always been non optimized for serving commands). I suggest you play around with this file a bit, it's very powerful, notably for the schematics !